# Can't get 4 column footer to work and be responsive

Tags: php, html, css, footer

I'm trying to create this 4 column footer, with a copyright section at the bottom, but no matter what I try, it's unresponsive and completely broken.

Thank you all so much for your help with this issue! It has been greatly appreciated.

Here is the small code I have at the moment.

```css
html{-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased; -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale; -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;}
body{ font-size:14px; font-family: 'Montserrat', Gotham, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;}
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6{ font-weight:700; line-height: 1em; text-transform:uppercase; }
h1{ font-size:3em; margin-bottom:15px;}
h2{ font-size:2.2em; margin-bottom:15px;}
h3{ font-size:1.9em; margin-bottom:10px; margin-top:20px; }
h4{ font-size:1.5em; margin-bottom:10px; margin-top:15px;}
h5{ font-size:1.2em; margin:10px 0 5px; line-height:1.8em}
h6{ font-size:1em;}
p, label{margin:10px 0 10px; line-height:1.8em; font-size:1em; font-weight:300;}
ul, ol{margin:15px 0 15px 30px;line-height:1.8em; font-size:1em; }
strong{font-weight:700;}

.alignleft{text-align:left !important;}
.aligncenter{text-align:center !important; margin-left:auto !important; margin-right:auto !important;}
.alignright{text-align:right !important;}

.preload{height:0;}

a{ color:inherit; text-decoration:none; cursor:pointer;}
a:hover{cursor:pointer;}
#wrapper{position:relative; overflow-x:hidden;}
.wrap{max-width:1600px; margin:0 auto; position:relative;height:100%;}
.clear{clear:both !important; height:0 !important; padding:0 !important; margin:0  !important; float:none !important;}
blockquote{    padding:0 20px; margin-bottom:15px;}

/** FORM ELEMENTS **/

input[type=text],input[type=password],input[type=datetime],input[type=datetime-local],input[type=date],input[type=month],input[type=time],input[type=week],input[type=number],input[type=email],input[type=url],input[type=tel],input[type=color],input[type=search],select,textarea{border: 1px solid #AAA; height:auto; -webkit-border-radius:0; border-radius:0;  -webkit-box-shadow:none !important;  box-shadow:none !important;font-family: 'Montserrat', Gotham, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; padding:15px 20px; font-size:1em;}
select{-webkit-appearance:none;-moz-appearance: none; appearance: none; text-indent:10px; line-height:24px;border:1px solid #AAA; background:#FFF url(../images/select.png) no-repeat 97% center;}
select option:disabled{color:#AAA;}
textarea{height:140px;}
input[type=text]:focus, textarea:focus{border-color:#d0101f;}
input[type=submit], input[type=button], input[type=reset], .button{font-weight:normal; cursor:pointer; margin:10px auto; font-size:1em; border:none; display:inline-block; padding:20px; color:#FFF;background:#1a1a1a; text-transform:uppercase; text-align:center; min-width:100px;}
input[type=submit]:hover, input[type=button]:hover, input[type=reset]:hover{}

#back-to-top{width:32px; height:32px; line-height:30px; -webkit-border-radius:3px; border-radius:3px;  background:none; right:20px; bottom:20px; position:fixed;}
#back-to-top:hover{}
#imagelightbox{position: fixed; z-index: 9999; -ms-touch-action: none;touch-action: none;}
#imagelightbox-overlay{background-color: #FFF;background-color: rgba( 255, 255, 255, .9 );}

body#error{background:url(../images/404-bg.jpg) no-repeat top center; background-size:cover; height:100vh;color:#ffde16 !important;}
body#error .wrap{max-width:1200px;}
body#error .wrap .inner{padding-top:15vh; width:50%;}
body#error h1{font-size:15em; margin:0 0 200px;}

.social{list-style:none; margin:20px 0 0 20px; padding:0;}
.social li{display:block; float:left; width:30px; height:30px;  padding:0;-webkit-transition: all 400ms ease;-moz-transition: all 400ms ease;-ms-transition: all 400ms ease;-o-transition: all 400ms ease;transition: all 400ms ease; margin-right:10px; text-align:center;}
.social li a{display:block; font-size:14px; line-height:30px;  width:100%; height:100%; color:#666;}


/********* HEADER *********/

nav ul ul,nav ul ul:before{background:#FFF;position:absolute}
nav ul li:after,nav ul ul:before{content:'';margin:0 auto;left:0;right:0}
header{background:#FFF;position:fixed;top:0;left:0;width:100%;z-index:999;-webkit-transition:all .4s ease;-moz-transition:all .4s ease;-ms-transition:all .4s ease;-o-transition:all .4s ease;transition:all .4s ease; height:100px; box-shadow:0 0 20px rgba(0,0,0,.3);}
header .wrap{padding:0 30px}
header #logo{float:left;margin:0 30px 0 0;}
header #logo img{height:95px}
header nav{padding:0}
header .social{float:right; margin-left:30px; margin-top:30px; margin-right:10px;}

nav ul{margin:0;padding:0;text-transform:uppercase;cursor:pointer}
nav>ul li a,nav>ul li span{ padding:30px 0 20px; display:block; color:#72a464; font-weight:400; font-size:16px;}
nav li{display:inline-block;padding:0 20px;font-size:.8em;position:relative; text-align:center;}
nav li a,nav li span{color:#1a1a1a;}
nav li a i,nav li span i{display:block !important; font-size:16px !important; margin-bottom:10px;}
nav ul ul{-webkit-border-radius:3px;border-radius:3px;display:none;top:125px;left:50%;width:320px;z-index:3;padding:10px;text-align:left;transform:translate(-50%,0);-webkit-box-shadow:0 0 20px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.3);box-shadow:0 0 20px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.3)}

nav ul ul:before{top:-5px;width:10px;height:10px;transform:rotate(45deg)}
nav ul ul ul{top:0;left:240px}
nav ul ul.show{display:block}
nav ul ul li{float:none;line-height:30px;font-size:.9em}nav ul ul a{line-height:30px!important}
nav ul ul a:after{display:none}
nav ul li:after{position:absolute;bottom:0;height:5px;width:0;-webkit-transition:all .4s ease;-moz-transition:all .4s ease;-ms-transition:all .4s ease;-o-transition:all .4s ease;transition:all .4s ease}
nav ul li.active:after{width:100%}nav ul li.active>ul{display:block}
#mobile,nav .mobilenav{display:none}

/********* BANNERS *********/

#cta{padding:0; margin-top:0; position:relative; z-index:2;}
#cta .wrap{max-width:none;}
#cta .cta{float:left; width:25%; height:240px; text-align:center; padding:0;  position:relative;background:#FFF; overflow:hidden;}
#cta .cta img{display:block; margin:0 auto; object-fit:cover; max-width:100%;}
#cta .cta h4{text-transform:uppercase;color:#FFF; position:absolute; top:10px; left:0; right:0; text-align:center;text-shadow:2px 0 3px #000;}
#cta .cta p{ font-size:.9em; line-height:1.1em; margin:10px 25px; color:#333;}
#cta .button{margin:0 auto; width:360px; display:block;}

#secondary #hero{height:510px;background:url(../images/service.jpg) no-repeat center center; background-size:cover; position:relative;}
#secondary #hero .wrap{padding:0 50px;}
#secondary #hero h1{font-size:4em;text-shadow: 0 0 10px #000;  color:#FFF; padding-top:250px; text-align:center;}
#secondary #hero h1 span{ display:block;}

#secondary #contacthero{height:510px;background:url(../images/contact.jpg) no-repeat center center; background-size:cover; position:relative;}
#secondary #contacthero .wrap{padding:0 50px;}
#secondary #contacthero h1{font-size:4em;text-shadow: 0 0 10px #000;  color:#FFF; padding-top:250px; text-align:center;}
#secondary #contacthero h1 span{ display:block;}

#secondary #testihero{height:510px;background:url(../images/testimonial.jpg) no-repeat center center; background-size:cover; position:relative;}
#secondary #testihero .wrap{padding:0 50px;}
#secondary #testihero h1{font-size:4em;text-shadow: 0 0 10px #000;  color:#FFF; padding-top:250px; text-align:center;}
#secondary #testihero h1 span{ display:block;}

#content{padding:100px 0;}
#content .image, #content .content{width:50%; float:right; position:relative; min-height:400px; z-index:1; top:0}
#content .content{padding:30px 2% 30px 4%; width:44%; min-height:400px;}
#content .content.empty{top:0; height:0; display:none;}
#content .image .inner{position:absolute; top:0; left:0; right:0; width:100%; height:100%;}
#content .image.right, #content .image:nth-child(4n){float:left;}
#content .image img, #content .image iframe{position:absolute; top:0; left:0; height:100%; min-height:400px; z-index:1;}
#content .image iframe{width:100%; height:auto;}
#content .image:nth-child(4n) img{left:auto; right:0;}
#content .content:nth-child(5n){padding:30px 4% 30px 2%;}

#content hr{border:none; height:0; clear:both;margin:0;}
#content h2{font-size:3em;position:relative; margin-bottom:40px;color:#1a1a1a;}
#content h2 span{color:#ffc000;}
#content h3{font-size:2.5em;text-align:left; position:relative; margin-bottom:20px;color:#1a1a1a;}
#content h4{font-size:1.8em;color:#1a1a1a;}
#content h6{color:#696969;}

.work h2{text-align:center;color:#1a1a1a;}
.thumb{float:left; width:25%; position:relative; overflow:hidden; height:280px;}
.thumb img{position:absolute; top:50%; left:50%; display:block; transform:translate(-50%,-50%); min-height:100%; min-width:100%;}

#banner{height:400px; margin-bottom:50px; position:relative; overflow:hidden;}
#banner .image{background:url(../images/slider.jpg) no-repeat center center; background-size:cover; position:absolute; top:0; left:0;width:100% !important;}
.upright-monuments #banner .image{background-image:url(../images/user_uploads/uprightbanner.jpg);}
.flat-markers #banner .image{background-image:url(../images/user_uploads/markerbanner.jpg);}
.vases-benches #banner .image{background-image:url(../images/user_uploads/vasebanner.jpg);}

#testimonialbanner{background:url(../images/banner-testimonial.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; background-size:cover; color:#FFF; padding:150px 0; text-align:center;}
#testimonialbanner .wrap{position:relative}
#testimonialbanner h2{font-size:3em; padding-left: 20px; text-transform:uppercase;}
#testimonialbanner h2 span{ display:block; font-size:.5em;}
#testimonialbanner .message{position:relative;max-width:768px;margin:0 auto;z-index:2}
#testimonialbanner p{font-size:1em; padding-left: 20px;max-width:768px; margin:0 auto;}
.quote{position:absolute;z-index:1;color:#FFF;font-size:15em;font-family: 'Passion One', cursive; opacity:.3;}
.quote.open{top:-120px;left:-10%}
.quote.close{bottom:-120px;right:-10%}

#content .testimony { float: left; width: 28%; margin: 0 1% 20px; padding: 20px 1%; border: 1px solid #CCCCCC;}
#content .testimony .testimony-description {display : none;}
#content .testimony h4, #content .testimony h6 {text-align : center;}
#secondary #content .testimony h4 {font-size : 1.2em;}
#content .testimony h6 {height : 32px;}
#content .testimony p { height : 75px;}
#content .testimony .button {margin: 15px auto 0;display: block;width: 140px;}

#partnerbanner{background:url(../images/banner-partner.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; background-size:cover; color:#FFF; padding:150px 0; text-align:center;}
#partnerbanner h2{font-size:3em; padding-left: 20px; text-transform:uppercase;}
#partnerbanner h2 span{ display:block; font-size:.5em;}
#partnerbanner p{font-size:1em; padding-left: 20px;max-width:768px; margin:0 auto;}
#partnerbanner .button{background:#FFF; color:#665446;}

.team {width: 31%; float: left; margin: 20px 1%; position: relative;text-align: center;}
.team .img img{display:block; margin:0 auto; max-height:300px;}
.team h5{color:#1a1a1a;}

.contact-us .pad{padding-left:50px; padding-right:50px;}
.contact-us .address{text-align:right; color:#696969; border-bottom:1px solid #CCC; text-transform:uppercase; padding:10px 0;}
.contact-us .address strong{text-align:left; float:left; color:#1a1a1a; font-weight:normal;}

#map{height:420px; width:100%; margin-top:40px;}

.doc{width:100%; text-align:left; margin:20px 0; display:inline-block; height:auto;position:relative;background:#FFFFFF;overflow:hidden;border:1px solid #CCCCCC;}
.doc.video{width:48%}
.doc .cap{width:100%;background:#EEE;position:relative;height:180px;overflow:hidden;border-bottom:1px solid #CCCCCC}
.doc .cap .icon{width:60px;height:75px;margin:50px auto;text-align:center;color:#FFFFFF;position:relative;font-size:24px;line-height:75px;background: #1a1a1a;}
.doc .cap .icon:after{position:absolute;content:'';top:-15px;right:-15px;width:25px;height:25px;transform:rotate(45deg);background:rgba(255, 255, 255, .5)}
.doc p{margin:10px;line-height:16px; color:#1a1a1a;font-family: 'Montserrat';}
.doc.doc-small img{width:auto;max-height:100% !important;max-width:none}

/********* FOOTER *********/
footer{padding:40px 0;  color:#696969; background-image:url(../images/footer.png); background-size:100% 100%; height:400px;}
footer .wrap{padding:0 30px;}
footer .logo{float:left;}
footer .logo img{height:80px; display:block; margin:0 auto;}
footer ul{list-style:none; margin:0 ; padding:0;text-transform:uppercase; float:none;}
footer ul li{display:inline-block; padding:0 15px;}
footer .social{float:left;}
footer nav{float:right;}
footer nav ul li{float:none;}
footer nav ul li i{display:none !important;}
footer .mobilenav{display:inline-block;}
footer li.close.mobilenav{display:none;}
footer nav>ul li a, footer nav>ul li span{padding:10px 0 0;}
footer ul ul{display:none;}
footer #copyright{padding:0 0; margin-top:0; margin-right:60px;}
footer p{ margin:0 auto; text-align:right; font-size:.8em; text-transform:uppercase;}
footer .dev{background:url(../images/iwwlogo.png) no-repeat center center; text-indent:-999em; margin:0 0 0 20px; display:inline-block; width:20px; height:25px; position:absolute; bottom:0; right:40px;}

/********* IMAGE SLIDER *********/
#hero{position:relative; overflow:hidden; height:768px; z-index:1;}
.bxslider{margin:0 !important; position:fixed !important; overflow:hidden; height:768px; z-index:1; background:#111;}
.bxslider li{height:768px; position:relative; overflow:hidden;}
.bxslider li .wrap{z-index:2; text-align:left; padding:0 0;}
.bxslider .region{max-width:768px; position:absolute; top:40%; bottom:0; margin:auto 0;}
.bxslider .region.left{left:2%;}
.bxslider .region.left{max-width:600px;}
.bxslider .region.center{right:0; left:0; margin:0 auto; text-align:center;}
.bxslider .region.right{right:2%;}
.bxslider .title{}
.bxslider h2{font-size:5em; margin:0;}
.bxslider h3{font-size:5.8em; margin:0;}
.bxslider h5{font-size:1em; line-height:1.4em;}
.bxslider p{font-size:.85em;line-height:1.4em;}
.bxslider .button{ margin:60px auto 0; text-align:center;  text-transform:uppercase; width:140px; color:#1a1a1a; padding:15px 0;}
.bxslider li .background{position:absolute; top:0; left:0; right:0; width:100%; height:100%; margin:0 auto; z-index:1;}


form .row{max-width:800px;margin:0 auto; clear:both;}
form h4{ text-align:center; margin:30px auto 20px;}
form .button{ margin:30px auto 0; border-radius:30px; width:25%; background-color:#6db9fa; font-weight:bolder; font-size:16px}

form .panel{}
form .panel.hide{display:none;}

/********* ANIMATIONS *********/

@keyframes slidedown {
    from {top:-200px;}
    to {top:0;}
}

/********* MODAL AND OVERLAY *********/

.overlay {position: fixed;z-index: 9999;left: 0;right: 0;top: 0;width: 100%;height: 100%;opacity:.8;display: none; background:#000;}
.modal { position: fixed; top: -1000px;max-width: 800px;padding: 50px;left: 0;right: 0; margin: 0 auto;  z-index: 10000;-moz-transition: all 400ms linear;-ms-transition: all 400ms linear;-o-transition: all 400ms linear;transition: all 400ms linear;-webkit-transition: all 400ms linear; background:#FFF; box-shadow:0 0 40px rgba(0,0,0,.3);}
.modal .inner {position: relative;overflow-y: scroll;min-height: 30vh;max-height:75vh;}
.modal .modalclose {color: #c2c2c2;position: absolute;top: 10px;right: 20px;font-size: 3em;}

*, *:before, *:after {box-sizing: border-box;}

.controls {padding: 1rem; text-align:center;}
.control {position: relative; display: inline-block; cursor: pointer; background:none; border:none; font-size:1em;font-family: 'Montserrat'; text-transform:uppercase;color:#696969;}
.mixitup-control-active{color:#1a1a1a;}
.mixitup-control-active[data-filter]:after {position:absolute; content:''; width:100%; height:3px; bottom:-5px; left:0; right:0; background: #1a1a1a;}
.control[data-filter] + .control[data-sort] {margin-left: .75rem;}

.container {padding: 1rem; text-align: left;font-size: 0.1px;}
.container:after { content: ''; display: inline-block; width: 100%;}

.mix, .gap { display: inline-block;vertical-align: top; float:left;}
.mix { width:23%; margin:20px 1%; height:200px;position: relative; overflow:hidden;}
.mix[style*="display: none;"]{height:0; padding:0;}
.mix[style*="display: none;"] img{height:0; width:0;}
.mix a{position:absolute;}
.mix img{max-width:100%;}
.mix:before {content: ''; display: inline-block; padding-top: 56.25%;}

#contactform1{
  text-align:center;
  margin-bottom:40px;
  color:#1a1a1a;
}
#contactform1 .sendmessagetext{
  padding-top:50px;
  text-transform:none;
  padding-bottom:35px;
}
#contactform1 form{
  width:50%; margin:0 auto;
}
```

```html
<footer>
 <div class="wrap">
 <a href="<?=$SITEURL;?>" class="logo"><img src="<?=$SITEURL;?>/images/logofooter.png" alt="<?=$SITENAME;?>"></a>
   <nav>
   <?php echo $objmenu->showTopMenu(0);?>
   </nav>
  <div class="clear"></div>
  <div id="copyright">
  <p class="copy">Copyright 2017 <?php echo date('Y'); ?> <?=$SITENAME;?> Residential Cleaning & Organizing. All Rights Reserved.</p>
  </div>
     <div class="clear"></div>
  <a href="http://integratedwebworks.com" class="dev" target="_blank" rel="canonical" title="Developed by Integrated Webworks">Developed by Integrated Webworks</a>
  <a href="#" id="back-to-top" title="Back to top"><i class="fa fa-arrow-up"></i></a>
 </div>
</footer>
</div>
<?php include_once("analyticstracking.php") ?>
```

[footer I'm trying to create](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VCQPE.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you use [Bootstrap](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/grid/#all-breakpoints) if you want to make your life easier. Easy to use and responsive ready.

```
<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-3">col</div>
  <div class="col-md-3">col</div>
  <div class="col-md-3">col</div>
  <div class="col-md-3">col</div>
 </div>
</div>
```

or you can do this:

```
<div class="container">
 <div class="footer">
  <div class="col-1">col</div>
  <div class="col-2">col</div>
  <div class="col-3">col</div>
  <div class="col-4">col</div>
 </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
    width: 900px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.footer {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
}
.col-1,
.col-2,
.col-3,
.col-4 {
    width: 25%;
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: This is what I have now at the moment: 

http://143.95.237.35/~bluehydra/

I'm not sure what I did wrong.

Comment: @JonnyDee can you add the css in it?

Comment: @JonnyDee I have updated your fiddle, just add the font color and other css in it, add paddings and margins also. https://jsfiddle.net/3q6kqL1o/1/

Comment: I'm confused, that didn't change anything :c

Comment: when it goes to mobile size, all the text just completely goes off the screen.

Comment: @JonnyDee https://jsfiddle.net/3q6kqL1o/5/ Sorry, This should be the link the previous one is jsfiddle.net/3q6kqL1o/1. When you go mobile you need to add a media query. Added media query if max-width is 768px

Comment: Here it is now: http://143.95.237.35/~bluehydra/contact-us
Still trying to get it to look like this: http://i.imgur.com/2JbnAel.jpg

Comment: Please apply the CSS on the footer.

Comment: .fcontainer {
    width: 900px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.ffooter {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
}
.col-1,
.col-2,
.col-3,
.col-4 {
    width: 25%;
    float: left;
}
ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 0;
}
.footer-copyright {
width:100%;
float: left;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .fcontainer {
      width: 100%;
      margin: 0 auto;
  }
  .col-1,
  .col-2,
  .col-3,
  .col-4 {
    width: 100%;
    float: none;
  }
} is in my CSS file and it's all linked and working.

Comment: Yeap! I see it already, my bad. Actually, it's working fine now, all you need to do is to add an adjustment on the width of the container, paddings, and margins, font sizes. Just try to learn to and play along with the CSS and you will get what you want to achieve. I already provided you the answers, you just need to do a little more tweak to make it like in the image.